# Local Shortcode Using Wordpress Custom Fields

Tags: customization, shortcode

I'm trying to figure out a way to call a custom field that is given a value in the back end but I'm getting no where right now. I know how to display it using PHP but not how to create a shortcode to display it.

I'm hoping to create a custom field and present the value on the front end of my website by using a shortcode in the text.

For Example:

Custom Field = local_area

Value = Liverpool

Then within the page, write "If you're looking for builders in **[local_area]** call ..." - This will then display **"Liverpool"** - Then I can create multiple pages / areas and simply change the Custom Field value to whatever area I require.

Is this possible?

Kind Regards,
Dean

Comment: Edit your question to show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called Just Variables - which is doing just that https://wordpress.org/plugins/just-wp-variables/ - you can have a look at its code and it will provide you with the best explanation on how to do that. (or you can alternatively just use the plugin.)